# how to force conan 1.x to install without download dependencies

Tags: conan

I need to fetch the content of a binary package. We usually creates our package system flavors, only Release/Debug, and no options. Our recipes usually looks like

```py
from conans import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeDeps

class Base(ConanFile):
    name = "base-cmake-pkg"

    # We define settings so that this package will agnostic to the OS,
    # architecture, compiler. Only support build_type.
    settings = "build_type"

    options = None

    # Define the default source folder
    exports_sources = "src/*"

    # We will be using 'CMakeDeps' generator:
    # https://docs.conan.io/1/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html
    generators = "CMakeDeps"

    def package_info(self):
        # Change the name of the package in the CMake world to respect the
        # CamelCase convention CMake likes.
        # When the lib will be installed in the consumer app, it will install
        # this package with a `FindMyWonderfulPackage.cmake` file instead of
        # `Findmy_wonderful_package.cmake`.
        self.cpp_info.name = ''.join(
            word.title() for word in self.name.replace("-", "_").split('_')
        )

        # indicate the list of directories that contain the libraries (in any format),
        # so that a consumer can import them automatically in its workspace with a simple
        # command like:
        #   - self.copy("*", src="@libdirs", root_package="face-common-arxml", folder=True)
        # see https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/methods.html#imports
        self.cpp_info.libdirs = ["lib"]
```

I would expect a `conan install` to the following recipe will download without trying to rebuild:

```py
import pathlib

from conans import ConanFile

class MyConsumerRecipe(ConanFile):
    name = "my-comsumer-recipe"
    version = "0.1.0"

    settings = "build_type"

    options = None

    def requirements(self):
        # Copy content of the given copy_folder path into the package
        self.requires("base-cmake-pkg/1.0.2@xxx/stable")

    def imports(self):
        self.copy("*", dst="/path/where/i/want/to/copy/the/content", src="", keep_path=True)
```

```bash
$ conan install --build=never .
...
Building package from source as defined by build_policy='missing'
...
Packages
    base-cmake-pkg/1.0.2@xxx/stable:5169407f8735227b248fa703db6322677006a6f1 - Build

Installing (downloading, building) binaries...
base-cmake-pkg/1.0.2@xxx/stable: WARN: Build folder is dirty, removing it: ...
```

You see that I want to automatically retrieve the content of this package. I do not want to use `conan download` that requires to know the package id (i do not know it beforehand) and need to dig manually into the conan cache.

1. Why `--build=never` isn't respected?
2. Why does it tries to recompile despit using the same `settings=Release` ?

For information, here is the `conan inspect` output of the package i want to just download without rebuid:

```
$ conan inspect base-cmake-pkg/1.0.2@xxxx/stable
name: base-cmake-pkg
version: 1.0.2
url: ...
homepage: None
license: ...
author: ...
description: None
topics: None
generators: CMakeDeps
exports: None
exports_sources: src/*
short_paths: False
apply_env: True
build_policy: missing
revision_mode: hash
settings: build_type
options: None
default_options: None
deprecated: None
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: ``--build=never`` in Conan 1.X has less precedence than in-recipe ``build_policy = "missing"`` that is the thing that is allowing the package to build (it is building because the binary is missing, it would fail with "missing binary" error otherwise). This has been changed in Conan 2.0, but 1.X ``build_policy`` still highest priority

Comment: To know why it is not using the existing binary, more information would be needed: The full output of the ``conan create`` of the first package, the full output of the ``conan install`` of the consumer package, etc. I'd suggest filing a ticket in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, which is better suited for this kind of support

Comment: I managed to get it working by changing default_python_requires_id_mode. The défaut value was kind of weird, even when the base python recipe does not change of version, use channel or revision, it still fallback to build when it has been packed on another system, even if I explicitly say « self.info.clear » in the package_id method.

Comment: It seems that could be a bug, it is true that ``self.info.clear()`` doesn't remove the influence of ``python_requires``. There is a PR to fix that for Conan 2.0 in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/pull/15285 (this is the reason it is better to use https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues than here in SO, this feedback is more useful there)

Comment: I opened one issue already but didn't get the expected answer (= it comes from your `default_python_requires_id_mode` somehow.

conan 2 is really too hard to migrate to now, packages are not compatible, recipe needs to be changed, package promotion is not possible, ... what a pity they broke too many things to prevent smooth transition

Comment: Most of ConanCenter is now compatible with Conan 2.0, I think there is less than 20% of packages not compatible. Can you please link the issue?